# Equivalent graphics card

Tags: graphics-cards

At the moment I am using this computer:

```
Motherboard Name: Asus P8P67 (3xPCI, 2xPCI-E x1, 2xPCI-E x16, 4xDDR3 DIMM, Audio, Gigabit LAN, IEEE-1394)
Motherboard Chipset: Intel Cougar Point P67, Intel Sandy Bridge  
CPU: Quad-core Intel Core i7-2600K, 4400 MHz (43 x 102)  
RAM: 16GB (4x4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM)
DIMM1: G Skill ECO F3-12800CL8-4GBECO -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (9-9-9-28 @ 800 MHz) (8-8-8-25 @ 711 MHz) (7-7-7-22 @ 622 MHz)
DIMM2: G Skill Ares F3-1600C9-4GAB -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (11-11-11-28 @ 800 MHz) (10-10-10-27 @ 761 MHz) (9-9-9-24 @ 685 MHz) (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz) (7-7-7-19 @ 533 MHz) (6-6-6-16 @ 457 MHz)
DIMM3: G Skill ECO F3-12800CL8-4GBECO -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (9-9-9-28 @ 800 MHz) (8-8-8-25 @ 711 MHz) (7-7-7-22 @ 622 MHz)
DIMM4: G Skill Ares F3-1600C9-4GAB -- 4GB DDR3-1600 SDRAM (11-11-11-28 @ 800 MHz) (10-10-10-27 @ 761 MHz) (9-9-9-24 @ 685 MHz) (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz) (7-7-7-19 @ 533 MHz) (6-6-6-16 @ 457 MHz)
Graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series
3D-Accelerator: AMD Radeon HD 6850 (Barts)  
Power supply: be quiet - Dark Power Pro (80 Plus Gold) - Model: BQT P9-550W  
case: AeroCool RS-9 Professional
```

Unfortunately, I'm extremely bad at hardware. The graphics card is now broken and I need a new one with the following requirements:

1. Hopefully better than the old one, but at least the same performance
2. A GeForce
3. One that supports GPU rendering (the old one does not, at least Adobe Premiere is telling me)
4. And of course one that fits in the system

Do you know a graphics card with these specifications?
I thought that I can get such a graphics card with a maximum of 600€. However, I am also willing to go a little higher if this is necessary, but I don't think so, based on amazon and co.

**UPDATE**
at the moment there are only two graphic cards mentioned in this thread:
GTX 980 and GTX 980 TI.
the first is relatively old and the second is not (yet) supported by adobe. Is this support guaranteed in the future? or does somebody has an other GPU idea? maybe with a similar performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend the gtx 980 TI.

**Pros:**

- It is a geforce.
- It performs [WAY](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-980-Ti-vs-AMD-HD-6850/3439vsm7743) better than your old card.
- Draws 250 W, so with your power supply, you should be able to handle it.
- Compatible with your [motherboard](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/2c6kCJ), and your case. This card is 282mm, and your case advertises a [maximum length](http://www.quietpc.com/ae-rs9-group) of 295mm.
- Costs about 650 USD, which (according to google) is less than 600€.

**Cons:**

- <s>Very modern, definitely supports rendering.</s> *Probably* supports rendering. It isn't [officially listed](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html) on adobe's list of support GPUs, but it probably works anyway. You might have some tinkering/hacking to get it to work. Also, there are some benchmarks showing [unsupported cards](https://www.studio1productions.com/Articles/Premiere-Benchmark.htm), including the standard GTX 980, working well.

As a side note, right now this is pretty much the best GPU on the market. The Titan X outperforms it, but is significantly more expensive. This card is a great choice for what you have described. If you want something a little bit cheaper, you could go with a regular GTX 980 which will save you about 100€.

If you're scared by this card not being supported, you could go with the GTX 780.

**Pros:**

- It is officially supported.
- [Some benchmarks](https://www.studio1productions.com/Articles/Premiere-Benchmark.htm) show it outperforming the 980 TI, which is strange since it is significantly less powerful.

**Cons:**

- Less powerful.
- Older. It was released in 2013.
- Half the VRAM. (3 GB vs 6 GB)
- Expensive for a card that is 2, almost 3 generations old.

Personally, I would still recommend the 980 TI. I don't think it's worth it to drop 600 on a 2-generation old card. Hopefully future versions of premier will officially support the newest cards better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37641/discussion-between-dj-mcmayhem-and-christopher2007).

Comment: The 980 Ti [isn't on Adobe's list of officially supported graphics cards in Premiere](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html).  It'll probably work, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: oh damn, ok, I am using Premiere CC most of the time, so do you know something comparable with rudimentary same performance that is supported from adobe?

Comment: @christopher2007 Do you need a gpu for anything other than Premier? I'm looking into this, and I'll update my answer once I can give a better one.

Comment: At a glance the list doesn't feature anything newer than 2013 so it's most likely just not updated.

Comment: My friend edits using Premiere Pro CC with his 980, and hasn't had any problems yet

Comment: @JanDorniak, that's my guess too, hence the "it'll probably work".

Comment: I am using the gpu for Cinema 4D and Premiere CC. that's the main use, then also a littlebit of gaming, but nothing cracy. the only really stressful thing are the render times for a finished composition, because my old gpu did not supports rendering, so rendering is only on my cpu possible :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure something like VAT makes stuff about 10-20% more expensive in most of Europe, compared to what is expected from exchange rates. EDIT: Looks like the 980ti is ~640 Euros for Germany.

Comment: I would take the GTX 980 TI, looks like a very nice gpu, BUT the problem with adobe makes me a little bit nervous :S I have no idea it the support will come in the next year or not and I plan to use this gpu at least three or four years... so this sould be planned

Answer (score 2):

You should not go with a card with more than 200W TDP as you have only a 550W power supply. It might work, it might not.

600 EUR is way too high of a budget for just a new graphics card. If you want an equivalent graphics card to the 6850, you could go for a GTX 960. It's faster than the 6850 in fact, and consumes similar amount of power(120W for the 960, 127 for the 6850).
Ultra-high end cards like the 980 and 980Ti will be overkill for you, since your PC is old, and they're pretty fast, over 4 times as fast(or even faster) for the 980Ti. The 980Ti also consumes a lot of power, 250W.

If you want to go for a bit of futureproofing, go with a 970 or an upcoming Pascal card. The 970 is an awesome card at $330 with a power consumption of 145W. Pascal cards are new ones coming with an architecture change, meaning they'll be significantly faster for the same amount of money. But you'll have to wait two months for them.

Comment: I have an r9 290 (275w) and a 500w power supply. Everything works fine.

Comment: That line is intended to be a guide - you'll have a different config than the OP.